# UWP - Serial Port over bluetooth on Xamarin forms

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to connect to fiscal printer using serial port in xamarin.forms application.
I managed to make it work on android, but I have some troubles with UWP.
I am currently testing it on desktop if it matters.

await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync() - this line never returns, no matter whether I call it with selector or not.

```
var sel = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM7");

var coll = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(sel);
```

It just hangs. Anybody knows how to use FindAllSync / has a similar problem? I've found some examples on the web, but they do not seem to work, the method always hangs for me.

I also tried to use a different approach and use devicewatcher, I was able to get the list of all devices and the bluetoothdevice object, however I couldn't create a serialport for it.